How to prevent HTML entities in query parameters from being escaped when using sanitize in Rails?
I'm working on a Rails application where I need to sanitize user inputs, including URLs, using ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize. However, when sanitizing URLs that contain query parameters (such as &, ?, and =), they are being escaped into HTML entities, which breaks the URL formatting.
Current Output
/?suamnth=123&amp;samala=456
Expected Output
/?suamnth=123&samala=456
I need to continue using sanitize across my application to handle broader use cases, but for URLs with query parameters, I want to prevent the conversion of these characters (&, ?, =) to their HTML-encoded equivalents (&, etc.).
PS: I did try using below
example = "/?suamnth=123&samala=456"
sanitized_example = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(example, tags: %w[& ? =], attributes: [])

puts sanitized_example


What type of input is actually being sanitized?  Maybe you can build your own HTML scrubber using an existing library like loofah which is the underlying library rails uses (and you are using now). There is also sanitize which offers a lot of flexibility but both are HTML sanitizers, which, while you are using one currently, it is unclear if this is what you need.
